# after update to newest macOS, pod update gives an error

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

Following the latest macOS, I get the following issue:

```
pod update
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

does someone have a tip how to address this?  It worked fine before the update.

Comment: try reinstalling cocoapods. MacOS 10.13 (High Sierra) updated the system ruby from 2.0.0 to 2.3.3

Comment: Thanks!  A reinstall of cocoapods fixed the issue